# How to use PHP variable as CSS id?

Tags: php, css

Is it possible to write PHP in CSS?

I'm listing data from database, and getting the `id` from db to `<div>` `id` as well. It's almost working, But I have no idea how to add the `id` in CSS too. e.g:

The way I did it in HTML & JS below:

```
<div id= <?php echo $data['id']??''; ?>>
```

```
$("#<?php echo $data['id']??''; ?>").click(function(){
```

Comment: Welcome! What are you actually trying to style for each `div`? You may want to use a `class` instead of an `id`. If you are trying to style multiple elements all *completely* differently based on an `id`, you may want to consider using a preprocessor (SCSS/SASS) to output the CSS for you using SASS/SCSS functions. Also, your PHP won't write to CSS, unless you inline the CSS on each element, or setup a CSS Property/var on each element, e.g. `style="--backround-color: #000"` or something.

Comment: Thank you! Adding the style to each element solved the problem! Now the style gets generated with the html elem itself.

Comment: Awesome, glad you got it figured out!

Comment: to start with you could do : `<?php echo'<style>#'data['id']'{/* your style here */}</style>';?>`  right after closing your div. You might even echo your style into a style attribute. **edit**  *funny how sometimes connection can be so slow to not show previous comments.*

Comment: @disinfor I was listing names under each other. The initial size was height: 100px, width: 400px. If I'm clicking it, the div opens to height: 500px, width: 600px or around that, to reveal more data about the name. If I set the same id to all div's, the function only works on the first one. So without any better ideas, I generated custom id from database for div's, and generated the function for every div containing the id variable code. All with using php fetch. But thanks for the custom id code, everything is waay more complicated now! Hope you can understand at least half of it!

Comment: I think i could live with it from now on, If i could solve only one more problem. Its the filtering. I just cant get any solution for that. If you have a minute, pls take a look at that one instead. link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75566759/how-to-list-html-elements-with-condition-from-dropdown-complicated-edition

Comment: @IstvánBalogh you really don't need `ids` for what you are trying to do. Show us an example the HTML you have and what you want it to do. Like I commented on your other question, this is an [XY](https://xyproblem.info/) problem. You just started to code, so that is going to happen. Again, I think this is *way* more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: @disinfor Someone just helped me making the function way simpler, so know it works perfectly! Thank you for you effort!!

Answer (score 0):

You do it the same way:

```
<style>
#<?php echo $data['id']?> {
    color: green;
}
</style>
```

I don't see the point of using `??''` in any of this code. If `$data['id']` isn't set, this will create an empty ID, which is not valid. You should ensure that `$data['id']` is always set.

However, creating unique styles and click functions for each ID seems like poor design. If you want the same style and click listener for all the items created in this loop, give them a common class and use that in the CSS and jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I did try to set the style and function uniformly, but unfortunately only the first html element works that way. Generating the css and js codes as well solved the problem.