# How to list html elements with condition from dropdown? (complicated edition)

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I'm building a website where I'm listing businesses. The page where I'm listing them has a filter by location.

The hard part is that the id of the div block that contains the business data, and the location gets generated, so it makes all the code a little more complicated. It's almost working. If the location in the div doesn't match the dropdown's one, it gets hidden.But doesn't reappear when they're matching. How could I make it work?

```
 <script>
        $('#dropdowncounty').on('change', function(){
            var e = document.getElementById("dropdown");
            var value = e.value;  
          if ('<?php echo $data['county']??''; ?>' == e.value) {
            $("#<?php echo $data['id']??''; ?>").show();
          } else if ('<?php echo $data['county']??''; ?>' !== e.value){
            $("#<?php echo $data['id']??''; ?>").hide();
          }  
        });
    </script>
```

I just started coding, and learnt everything on the internet.Don't be so hard on me! Please if you don't want/can't help just keep scrolling. If something's not clear, comment and I'm editing the question.

Comment: I suspect there is some mixing-up here of server-side and client-side responsibilities. Does your PHP render a `<div>` for _each_ country or _only_ the one identified by `$data['country']`? And where do the values of `$data['id']` and `$data['country']` come from?

Comment: Based on this question and your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75560648/how-to-use-php-variable-as-css-id?noredirect=1#comment133322832_75560648) I suspect this is a bit of an [XY](https://xyproblem.info/) problem. I believe you are making this more complicated than it needs to be. Instead of showing us the code you are using, show us the **HTML** output of your `divs`. Show us what you want to output (HTML) and what you expect the code to do.